# Como gravar texto e imagem juntos no mysql com asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Estou criando um fórum na minha aplicação e gostaria de saber como salvar imagem e texto juntos no Mysql, como no campo mensagem haverá um editor WYSIWYG então terei que gravar tanto texto quanto imagens, entre outros. Que tipo de campo utilizo no Mysql e como faço para salvar os dois dentro do asp.net mvc?

Não utilizo o EF!

Comment: No mesmo campo ou em campos separados?

Comment: No mesmo campo. Estava vendo Blob mas quando coloquei um texto no Mysql neste tipo de campo ele ficou assim: Para realizar a atividade I Ã© necessÃ¡rio fazer uma redaÃ§Ã£o sobre o tema computaÃ§Ã£o grafica

Comment: Sim, porque ele grava uma série de bits e possivelmente está havendo um problema com a codificação. Eu não usaria blob pro campo de descrição e hospedaria as imagens em algum lugar.

Comment: Mas como farei para separar texto de imagem, fora isso hospedar as imagens fora do site não tira a privacidade do mesmo?

Comment: "Tirar a privacidade"? Minha sugestão é para hospedar as imagens dentro do fórum mesmo.

Comment: Certo então você diz para neste caso eu ter um editor normal de texto e um openfile para a imagem?

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso. Eu faria um esquema que sobre o arquivo em Ajax pro servidor enquanto se está editando o texto.

Comment: Entendi fazer o upload da imagem enquanto o texto é editado, mas a imagem seria inserida no textarea também? ou seria colocado no openfile?

Comment: A ideia seria mostrar a imagem no textarea.

Comment: mas como funcionaria isso sendo que os dados do textarea não foram enviados no form? o ajax faz isso? Estou tentando imaginar o cenário mas esta dificil

Comment: [Veja isto](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Quick-Upload-Example).